# VBA using two methods and passing data

Tags: vba, excel

I want to retrieve data from a website, store it in a string and use string functions to put it in rows and columns: comma is for columns and semicolon is new row.

I used the two methods separately and they worked, but they are not working like this:

`gettse()` is supposed to retrieve data in a cell, and `split2()` should separate the string. 
When I run each method, they work fine. Of course, I use `split1()` which is similar to `split2()` but does not have an argument and read from `cell(1,1)`.

Could you please tell what is the problem of this code which uses both of them.

My guess was that it depends on the speed of the internet, and when it is retrieving data, the second method has already run. I used a 5-second delay, but it did not work.

```
Sub main()
    gettse
    Dim data As String
    data = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value
    split2 (data)
End Sub


Sub gettse()

    Set shFirstQtr = Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1)
    Set qtQtrResults = shFirstQtr.QueryTables _
    .Add(Connection:="URL;http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/ClientTypeAll.aspx", _
    Destination:=shFirstQtr.Cells(1, 1))

    With qtQtrResults
        .WebFormatting = xlNone
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebTables = "1"
       .Refresh
    End With

End Sub


Sub split2(data As String)

    Dim aColumns, aRows
    Dim x As Long
    aRows = split(data, ";")

    For x = 0 To UBound(aRows)
        aColumns = split(aRows(x), ",")
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, UBound(aColumns) + 1) = aColumns
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue, is it throwing any error or is your actual result different from expected result, if so, can you share sample input and expected output?

Comment: In your last post, I advised it was probably due to you overlapping the datasource, shown in your screen shot underneath, your split code works, and I've just replicated with another data source and it doesn't overlap, try starting your pasting in a different sheet.

Comment: are you saying that when you run main() it does not run the other two subs?

Comment: @Matt_Roberts The subs are run separately, but it does not return what I expected, I guess retrieving data from web and put it in a cell takes time, which it seems that delay in almost all part of the code is not working.

Comment: @Siva The subs return all desired data when they are run separately, but when I use them in this order, it does not. It seems retrieving data is an issue would not be solved even whit your solution or delay.

Answer (score 1):

In your last post, I advised it was probably due to you overlapping the datasource, shown in your screen shot underneath the cell you are using, your split code works, and I've just replicated with another data source and it doesn't overlap, try starting your pasting in a different sheet

[image]

Comment: I know that the code should work, but it did not on my computer, and it might depend on network connection and computer speed.

Answer (score 1):

If the Issue is due to non availability of data in `Cells(1,1)` and a call to `split2` is happening even before that , then you can include a `Do While` loop to check the value of `Cells(1,1)` before you call `split2`

```
Sub main()
Do While Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value  ""
  gettse
Loop

Dim data As String
data = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value
split2 (data)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem lies with .Refresh line. Here is the help page for the Refresh method

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197503.aspx

hen the BackgroundQuery sets False it'll wait until all data are retrieved. If it is true then it will proceeds with what it already has.

The only differece with the code I asked  is this line:

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

The modified code that works is:

```
Sub main()
    gettse
    Dim data As String
    data = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value
    split2 (data)
End Sub


Sub gettse()

    Set shFirstQtr = Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1)
    Set qtQtrResults = shFirstQtr.QueryTables _
    .Add(Connection:="URL;http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/ClientTypeAll.aspx", _
    Destination:=shFirstQtr.Cells(1, 1))

    With qtQtrResults
        .WebFormatting = xlNone
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebTables = "1"
       .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub


Sub split2(data As String)

    Dim aColumns, aRows
    Dim x As Long
    aRows = Split(data, ";")

    For x = 0 To UBound(aRows)
        aColumns = Split(aRows(x), ",")
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, UBound(aColumns) + 1) = aColumns
    Next

End Sub
```